# JQuery UI addClass callback function being called immediately

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, addclass

I am trying to add a class then remove it using JQuery UI's addClass callback. The problem is the callback is called immediately. I have tried it a few different ways but no matter what the callback calls immediately and never waits for the animation to happen.

**Update:** I made the changes to easing that were suggested but still the callback fires immediately.

Here are the ways I have tried:

**Method 1**

```
function pulsateUp() {
    text.addClass("pulsate-up", 1000, "easeInQuad", pulsateDown);
}
function pulsateDown(){
    console.log("Removing class");
    text.removeClass("pulsate-up", 1000, "easeInQuad");
}
```

**Method 2**

```
function pulsateUp() {
    text.addClass("pulsate-up", 1000, "easeInQuad", function(){pulsateDown()});
}

function pulsateDown(){
    console.log("Removing class");
    text.removeClass("pulsate-up", 1000, "easeInQuad");
}
```

**Method 3**

```
function pulsateUp() {
    text.addClass("pulsate-up", 1000, "easeInQuad", function(){
        console.log("Removing class");
        text.removeClass("pulsate-up", 1000, "easeInQuad");
    });
}
```

Here is my css in case it has anything to do with the issue:

```
#animate-demo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 99%;
    color: #0972a5;
    font-size: 48px;
    transition: 1s;
}
.pulsate-up {
    transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery UI, `easeIn` is not a valid easing, the options are

- linear
- swing
- _default
- easeInQuad
- easeOutQuad
- easeInOutQuad
- easeInCubic
- easeOutCubic
- easeInOutCubic
- easeInQuart
- easeOutQuart
- easeInOutQuart
- easeInQuint
- easeOutQuint
- easeInOutQuint
- easeInExpo
- easeOutExpo
- easeInOutExpo
- easeInSine
- easeOutSine
- easeInOutSine
- easeInCirc
- easeOutCirc
- easeInOutCirc
- easeInElastic
- easeOutElastic
- easeInOutElastic
- easeInBack
- easeOutBack
- easeInOutBack
- easeInBounce
- easeOutBounce
- easeInOutBounce

[Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/gq0taj6p/1/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out about easing and providing a working example. I see how your code works and I have my code exactly the same but it doesn't work. Could it have anything to do with the class I'm adding having a css transform? I will post my css just in case that has something to do with it.

Comment: jQuery UI animates the changes in the classes, so CSS animations would just add to that and probably not work very well. If you just want the CSS animation, you don't need jQuery UI, but you would have to listen for the `TransitionEnd` event instead or use keyframes